# Convert from NSString to float?

Tags: nsstring, floating-point

How can I convert this number to a float? It is 35.77091272818393, type NSString. The problem is that, if I use

```
[str doubValue]
```

it returns 35.770912.

---

I want to convert this string

```
NSString *tt =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.14f", 35.77091272818393 ];
```

to a float using

```
var=[tt floatValue];
```

but it does not have enough precision - it only returns 35.7709127 and not all the digits.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that the value `35.770912` you are seeing is the rounded double-precision floating point value.  If you want more decimal points, than you can use something like the following:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.14", @"35.77091272818393"];
```

This will print out the value with 14 decimal points, and you will see that the precision has not been lost in the floating point value.

---

You are having problems with the second part of your question because you're accessing the `floatValue` property of the string instead of the `doubleValue` property. The number you reference requires more precision than float provides.  You must store the number in a double-precision floating-point type.  Something like this should fix your problem:

```
NSString *tt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.14f", 35.77091272818393];
double var = [tt doubleValue];
```

Comment: my problem is, i want to affect this resultat 
NSString *tt =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.14f",  35.77091272818393 ]; to var=[tt floatValue]; but i have problem about precision beacause return to me only 35.7709127 and not all number

Comment: I added additional details to my answer to address your clarification.

Comment: Two days I was looking at this issue until I found this post. The above solution worked.